# Drone.IO - how to evenly distribute jobs between two agents / workers in a round robin fashion?

Tags: drone.io

My current CI setup is as follows:

- Machine #1 - Drone Server (`/bin/drone-server`)  + Drone Agent (`/bin/drone-agent`)
- Machine #2 - Drone Agent (`/bin/drone-agent`)

Running Drone 0.8.5.

Both agents seem to be connecting to the Drone Server just fine but unfortunately all the jobs are being processed by Machine #1 only.

I guess that both agents are racing to pick up jobs and the #1 is winning all the time but is there a way to force like a round robin mechanism to split the jobs evenly between two machines?

I don't want to remove concurrency to force the jobs to another machine as I want to evenly distribute the load. https://discourse.drone.io/t/worker-parallelism/736

I would appreciate any tips.